# How to get and image that my Spring boot API returns as FileSystemResource

Tags: java, android, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application deployed on a tomcat that's make me able to upload images from and android application. Now I'm trying to get that images. The problem is that my endpoint of my controller returns a FileSystemResource and I don't know how to handle it.

Endpoint:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getFotoPerfil", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
public FileSystemResource getFotoPerfil(@RequestParam("path") String path) {
    return utilitiesService.findInFileSystem(path);
}
```

The response I receive:

[image: response]

If I make the call with Postman, it works:

[image: postman]

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What do actually want to do with that response? Meaning, sure, your initial strategy is not correct, because the image file is not a `JSON` (to my knowledge, no image format is JSON). Now that we know this, what does it mean to handle this response? Are you showing it to someone on UI or just saving somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I want to show it on the UI. You are right, the main problem is that I make the call to the endpoint with a StringRequest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your client code seems to be assuming that it will be getting JSON. The controller is returning *an image* (although it's a PNG, even though you're inaccurately telling the client it's `image/jpeg`), which is binary data. In Java, this response should normally be handled as a `byte[]` instead of a `String`.

Comment: I see your point. I make the request with a StringRequest which returns a string. I found that many people implement their own MultipartRequest in order to upload/download images. I don't know if is the best way to do that, but I would try it.

Comment: Definitely works with a MultipartRequest. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Bocho I have no idea what tool you are using, but most of them directly support `byte[]` as a content holder specifically for cases of binary data. If Multipart works for you, that's okay too.